# establish aws DynamoDB connection using scala

Tags: java, database, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have been trying to create a DynamoDB client using scala. The client which I created was

```
val client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(
  new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(),
  PredefinedClientConfigurations.dynamoDefault
    .withRequestTimeout(config.dynamoRequestTimeoutMs)
    .withMaxConnections(config.dynamoMaxConnections))
client.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion(config.dynamoRegion))
```

But here, I am using the InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider() to provide the credentials(access key and secret key). Suppose I have the credentials at hand(access_key = "abcd" and secret_key = "xyz"). Is there a way such that I can create a DynamoDB client by providing the credentials I'm having? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` with an instance of `BasicAWSCredentials`:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials 

new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret)
```